# Inserting text with sed at start of line gives error

Tags: sed, quotes, msys2

I am trying to modify a file with sed but I get an error I do not understand:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Command:

```
sed -e 's/^/"asset\//' example.txt
```

Example file:

```
joe
john
peter
```

sed is from msys2:

```
which sed
```

> sed is an external : C:\msys64\usr\bin\sed.exe

When adding text to the end of each line the following works as expected:

```
sed -e 's/$/",/' y.txt
```

> joe",
>   john",
>   peter",

I am at a lost to understand what is wronghere.

Comment: Well, it should work. Can you please post the output of `sed --version` or `sed -v` to see what sed do you have?

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Comment: I *think* Windows does something weird with `^`. If you can't get rid of Windows (you're welcome) try putting the script in a file and using `sed -f file y.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT(solution on cygwin):*** Try following on cygwin `sed`, just tested on a system and it worked fine from command prompt. While using `'` single quotes with `sed` I am getting same error what OP is getting but while using `"` in `sed` I am able to get correct behavior of `sed`(expected one, to add `"` before each line)

```
sed -E "s/^/\"/"  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT2(taken reference from tripleee's comments):*** You could also save your sed command into a file named `file` with command `s/^/\"/` then run the `sed` code by doing, tested it successfully with cygwin `sed`.

```
sed -f file Input_file
```

---

---

***Alternate solution(tested and works on cygwin):*** I don't have cygwin with me so couldn't test on it, though your mentioned solution works fine for BASH. Could you please try following another approach once? I just tested this solution too on cygwin and it worked fine there (EDIT comment).

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1/' Input_file
```

Comment: Option one does nothing.

Comment: @Gerhard, Do you want to save output into Input_file itself? Because this is printing correct output for me on terminal.

Comment: @Gerhard, Please check my EDIT answer now and lemme know then? Both are tested and working fine for me.

Comment: OK Option 1 is working now. Looks like windows does something with the ^ when using single quotes.